# ClrDatagrid retain pagination state on routing

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Is there a way for the ClrDatagrid to retain the pagination state after being navigated away from and back to via my apps routes?  If I have a multipage server based datagrid, it does not remember the page it was on when it is navigated to.  It always sets back to page 1.

Comment: https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/pagination.
Two way binding with ```[(clrDgPage)]```

Comment: In addition to the above comment, the app will also need to preserve the page somehow it can be bound to `clrDgPage` when navigation brings the user back to the datagrid.

Answer (score 3):

So working off of the 2 comments above I used the 2 way binding along with storing/retrieving the page from sessionStorage to remember the page between navigation.  Works great.  Lesson learned to drill down on docs on element in question: Pagination - ClrDgPage.  Thanks for the help.

Here's the code from my component ts.  Var currentPage is used to bind to ClrDgPage:

```
  currentPage: number = 1;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let lastPage = sessionStorage.getItem("employee-current-page");
    if (lastPage) {
      this.currentPage = parseInt(lastPage);
    }
  }

  refresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.lastState = state;
    sessionStorage.setItem("employee-current-page", this.currentPage.toString())
    this.employeeService.listForGrid(state).subscribe((result) => {
        this.employees = result.content;
        this.total = result.totalElements;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      (error1) => {
        console.log(error1);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

And code from component html:

`<clr-datagrid #datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="refresh($event)" [clrDgLoading]="loading" >`

```
<clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="20" [clrDgTotalItems]="total" [(clrDgPage)]="currentPage">
  <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10,20,50,100]">Employees per page</clr-dg-page-size>
  {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}}
  of {{total}} employees
</clr-dg-pagination>
```

Comment: Any change you can post some snippets how you did this?

Comment: Yeah was just trying to fix.  I just copied code snippet into answer above.  The repo was private.

Comment: Thanks! And this `refresh` method is probably connected to the `clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="refresh($event)"`.

Comment: Added refresh html in as well